# Calculation of Least Square Matching

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares, affine-geometry

I am trying to understand and implement least square matching for images. However, I am having trouble with the theoretical part. In the [Gruen's Paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ea80/85172671e9870dfdb2b835d42c6f1f6fa5ef.pdf), I understood up to obtaining solution vector on page 5. However, I do not understand the what is $P$ here and how the function $g(x,y)$ is updated iteratively. Also I found another [document](https://engineering.purdue.edu/~bethel/main1.pdf) about the subject, which is simplified version. Again here, I do not understand how do they update the second image, since $\Delta$ and $V$ variables are not explained in the equation $V + B\Delta = f$.

Can anyone help me to understand this subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just write what I think is happening in the second paper you linked.

Let $g(x,y)$ and $h(x,y)$ be our image data, which are known. We write the transformation of $h$ to $g$ via the following model:
$$
g(x,y) = k_1h(a_1x+a_2y+a_3,b_1x+b_2y+b_3) + k_2
$$
so the transformation has a number of unknown parameters, which we can write as:
$$ \eta = [a_1,a_2,a_3,b_1,b_2,b_3,k_1,k_2] $$
Let the initial parameter vector be given by: $ \eta_0 = [1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0] $.

This can be rewritten as:
$$
F(\eta) = g(x,y)-k_1h(a_1x+a_2y+a_3,b_1x+b_2y+b_3) - k_2 = 0
$$
Unfortunately, this is quite difficult to solve, so instead we linearize it.

Recall that the linear approximation (i.e. first order Taylor approximation expanded about $\eta_0$) to $F$ can be written as:
$$
F_\mathcal{L}(\eta) = F(\eta_0) + (\eta-\eta_0)^T\nabla_\eta F
$$
In terms of the second paper you linked, it seems that $B:=\nabla_\eta F$, $v:=F(\eta_0)$, $\Delta := \eta-\eta_0$, and $f:=F_\mathcal{L}(\eta)$.

Comment: I did not expect something like Taylor expansion . Thanks for information about that. Also dou you have an idea about equation (11) in the document? because $k_1$ disappears mysteriously there.